# thread-safety of injected EntityManager in JSF environment

Tags: jsf, jpa, jboss, ejb-3.0

Are there any thread-safety issues or other code smells with the following pattern?

#### Stateless EJB3 bean injected with container-managed EntityManager:

```
@Stateless
public class ServiceA implements IServiceA.ILocal {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="foo")
    private EntityManager em
    ...
```

#### .. and then the View-scoped JSF-managed backing bean is injected with the above service bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PageFooController {
    @EJB
    private IServiceA.ILocal serviceA;
    ....
```

The deployment environment is JBoss 7 with the default Hibernate JPA implementation.

The reason I am asking is that under stress testing simulating hundreds of users we notice  mangled JPA entity values (values which don't exist in the database) which might suggest some race condition / thread unsafe access on the entity manager handling the JPA entities.

Comment: It looks more like a problem with your JPA component implementation or your database than a web application thread-safety issue.

Comment: So you don't see anything suspicious or unusual with the above pattern? When you say "your JPA component implementation" you mean the JPA POJOs I define and their annotations or the Hibernate implementation of the EntityManager?

Comment: When injecting a stateless session bean you get a proxy of the real ejb and when you invoke a method of that proxy you get a fresh ejb instance with a fresh entity manager. So the pattern you're using is correct. Probably you have to revise your entities, queries and data isolation.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I agree with Adrian. Also, you haven't shown your JPA component (your entity and the class/methods that operates on the entity) that saves the data.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks - I haven't shown you the entity and methods cause it's rather longish and I haven't yet the time to reproduce this behaviour in a narrowed-down example that would make sense to post.

Comment: @Adrian Mitev - I did some testing. In low load the EJB3 instance (the stateless session bean) is definitely the same (as reported by System.identityHashCode(this) on a method of the EJB bean). In high load however more instances are used but they are shared. But I understand that the EJB3 container takes care to serialize access to them so no worries there. The Entity Manager injected proxy is the same in all cases but the underlying Entity Manager (which you get via getDelegate()) is indeed a difference object on every method call. I suppose that's the normal behaviour of the container.

Comment: Are sure that you client transaction is wide enough to ensure consistency, i.e. are you invoking serviceA multiple times in PageFooController and expecting the invocations to commit together? If so you need to inject UserTransaction into PageFooController and call begin() /commit(). Why are you calling getDelegate()?

Comment: @Allen Parslow: No, I am not expecting multiple calls on serviceA to commit together. I am calling getDelegate() only for debugging / experimentation purposes to see the different instances of the underlying EntityManager. I.e. I do a: l.info("em is: "+System.uniqueHashCode(em.getDelegate())); Can you elaborate or provide pointers on the UserTransaction injected into backing bean pattern? Would that pattern allow me to avoid Lazy Initialization Exceptions in the web layer due to detached JPA objects returned by the EJB3 bean?

Comment: code in for example a servlet:
userService = (User service) ctx.lookup(...);
UserTransaction tx = (UserTransaction)ctx.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    tx.begin(); // comment out this line to get "failed to lazily initialize a collection" (hibernate as jpa provider)
User user = userService.getUserById(1);
user.getAccounts().iterator().next(); // lazy collection

I also assume your are not using the following: TransactionAttribute.REQUIRES_NEW